# Not being able to acces Interval in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, intervals

I am following a book tutorial on JS. And I stumbled on this problem...
The task was to "animate" a text title (and I achieve that) and where ever I click the "animation" should stop...

When I click on my first interval everything works, but on every other interval I get a message "**intervalB is not defined**", I know the problem is something about scopes, but I don't know what is the exact problem...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Interactive programming</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <h1 id="heading">Hello world!</h1>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

 <script>
// We'll fill this in next



var leftOffset = 0;
var topOffset = 0;



var moveHeading = function () {
$("#heading").offset({ left: leftOffset });

leftOffset++;

 if (leftOffset > 200) {
  leftOffset = 200;
  intervalB = setInterval(moveHeadingDown, 30);
  }
 };

intervalA = setInterval(moveHeading, 30);

var moveHeadingDown = function () {
$("#heading").offset({ top: topOffset });

 topOffset++;

  if (topOffset > 200) {
  topOffset = 200;
  intervalC = setInterval(moveHeadingRight, 30);
  }
 };

var moveHeadingRight = function () {
$("#heading").offset({ left: leftOffset });

 leftOffset--;

  if (leftOffset < 0) {
  intervalD = setInterval(moveHeadingUp, 30);

  leftOffset = 0;
  }
 };

var moveHeadingUp = function () {
$("#heading").offset({ top: topOffset });

 topOffset--;

  if (topOffset < 0) {
  topOffset = 0;
  }
 };

var clickHandler = function (event) {
clearInterval(intervalA);
clearInterval(intervalB);

console.log("Click!");
};

$("html").click(clickHandler);


  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need to set timers in to a global object or array.( It is impossible to store them in REDIS).

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi How can I do that?

Comment: you can add anything to global object ```global.myTimers = .... ``` and retrieve them every where ( in a process instance ).

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi Thank you :)